# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'nt.DirEntry' and 'str'

Tags: python

I need to downgrade a Python script written on 3.7.1 version to 3.6 version and I'm struggling to make it working.

Here the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import os


def replace_function(entries):
    with fileinput.FileInput(entries, inplace=True) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('OLD', 'NEW')
            print(line, end='')


def retrieve_files_function(folder):
    return os.scandir("work\\" + folder)


replace_function(retrieve_files_function('function'))
replace_function(retrieve_files_function('package'))
```

And here the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/replacer/replaces", line 17, in <module>
    replace_function(retrieve_files_function('function'))
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/replacer/replaces", line 8, in replace_function
    for line in file:
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\fileinput.py", line 250, in __next__
    line = self._readline()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\fileinput.py", line 331, in _readline
    self._filename + (self._backup or ".bak"))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'nt.DirEntry' and 'str'
```

I guess this would be the first of a few workarounds.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please.

Comment: Added stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @captnsupremo I was able to make it working with Python 3.6.8 in this way:

```
def retrieve_files_function(folder):
    return [f"work\\{folder}\\{name}" for name in os.listdir(os.path.join("work", folder))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `retrieve_files_function` is returning a list of `os.DirEntry` objects, but it looks like you want it to return a list of `str`. To be more clear, when you call `os.scandir()`, instead of just returning the name of the file, it returns an object that contains additional info about the file. If instead, you call `os.listdir()`, it will return just the filename as a string, and then I think your function should work.

Documentation on `os.listdir`, `os.scandir`, and `os.DirEntry` can all be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html

The code for `retrieve_files_function` would look like:

```
def retrieve_files_function(folder):
    return os.listdir(os.path.join("work\\", folder))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did what you suggest and now I get:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'my_function.fnc' -> 'my_function.fnc.bak'

Comment: Depending on your folder structure, you may need to ensure the list of filenames that gets generated has the right relative filepath. For example, we prepend `"work\\"` to the `listdir()` path. You may need to prepend the same thing to the filenames. For example: `[f"work\\{name}" for name in os.listdir(os.path.join("work\\", folder))]`